# Using HikariCP under DB failover senario

Tags: spring-boot, database-connection, hikaricp

I am considering using hikariCP with AWS RDS and would like to clarify some specifications of hikariCP regarding DB failover senario.

1. **Does HikariCP always validate connection after the connection is picked up from the pool and before the connection is used by the application?**
   According to the sentence "This is the query that will be executed just before a connection is given to you from the pool to validate that the connection to the database is still alive." in https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP, I guess connection validation is always performed.
   However, [this comment](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/406#issuecomment-136660574) seems to indicate that connection validation is not always performed.
2. **In case connection validation mentioned above is always performed, when the performed connection validation fails, is exception thrown to the application immediately or is another connection picked up from the pool without throwing exception?**
3. **In case another connection is picked up from the pool without throwing exception, is there any timeout settings of HikariCP for this connection pickup?**
   I am thinking `connectionTimeout` might be the one.

Comment: 1. No it depends on your configuration and you shouildn't use a validation query but JDBC4 connection validation should be preferred!. 2. it will invalidate the connection and get another one, 3. that is the one.

Comment: I understand that I should not configure original test query. I would like to clarify if the connection validation is always performed after the connection is picked up from the pool and before the connection is used by the application.

Answer (score 1):

Add these args to jvm for DNS refresh
-Dnetworkaddress.cache.ttl="60" -Dnetworkaddress.cache.negative.ttl="10" -Dsun.net.inetaddr.ttl=60 -Dsun.net.inetaddr.negative.ttl=1

checkForIpChange periodically and evict connections

```
private void checkForIpChange(HikariDataSource dataSource) {
        try {
            String ip = getIp(dataSource.getJdbcUrl());
            if (Objects.isNull(dataSourceIpMap.get(dataSource))) {
                dataSourceIpMap.put(dataSource, ip);
            } else if (!StringUtils.equals(ip, dataSourceIpMap.get(dataSource))) {
                log.info("writer ip changed, old is {} and new is {}", dataSourceIpMap.get(dataSource), ip);
                evictConnections(dataSource);
                dataSourceIpMap.put(dataSource, ip);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Caught exception in cname check", e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * soft eviction will add a new entry in the pool if the pool is not suspended, so suspend it
     * connection count is transient so take 10 zero samples to ensure full eviction
     * 60 sec wait time if all this does not work
     *
     * @param dataSource
     */
    private void evictConnections(HikariDataSource dataSource) {
        HikariPoolMXBean pool = dataSource.getHikariPoolMXBean();
        if (pool != null) {
            log.info("Active connection count is : {}, idle connection count is {} and total connection count is {}",
                    pool.getActiveConnections(), pool.getIdleConnections(), pool.getTotalConnections());
            log.info("suspending pool");
            pool.suspendPool();
            int zeroConnectionCount = 0;
            long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (long time = currentTimeMillis; time < currentTimeMillis + MAX_EVICT_WAIT_TIME_MILLS; time = time + 100) {
                pool.softEvictConnections();
                if (pool.getTotalConnections() == 0) {
                    zeroConnectionCount++;
                    if (zeroConnectionCount >= ZERO_CONNECTION_VALIDATION_COUNT) {
                        log.info("ZeroConnectionCount encountered {} times, so exiting loop", zeroConnectionCount);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            log.info("resuming pool");
            pool.resumePool();
        }
    }

    private String getIp(String url) throws URISyntaxException, UnknownHostException {
        URI aURL = new URI(url);
        aURL = new URI(aURL.getSchemeSpecificPart());
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(aURL.getHost());
        return address.getHostAddress();
    }
```